# How to get gender and birthday using Firebase Authentification in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'll use the decision made here https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/firebase-authentication-with-angular
At the moment you can get the following user data: **image, name, provider**.

How do I get more information? Interested in gender and age.

Tried, as it is written to add `provider.addScope()`, but apparently I am doing something "wrong" or not configured in the provider, to get this data. 
I would like to see a more advanced example, from the settings to the output in `console.log`.

Thank so much

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get those details, you're going to need to use the People API.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/people

Currently Firebase authentication just provides the basic public information (Name, email and profile photo).

More info about how to get gender and age.

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people